# Redux blocking on high volume websocket events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, websocket, redux-saga

I have a requirement in the app im currently building to fetch all data via a websocket, the issue is that there is no functionality to fetch *all* data via the websocket, and i have to fetch individual items from the websocket. This can mean up to 100+ events sent to the websocket on page load.

```
import { webSocketData } from "../actions";

const setupSocket = dispatch => {
  const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8889");

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    socket.onopen = () => {
      return resolve(socket);
    };

    socket.onmessage = event => {
      const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      dispatch(webSocketData(data));
      console.log(data.type);
    };
  });
};

export default setupSocket;
```

With the code above this means that 100 redux actions are dispatched which is resulting in very sluggish performance for me.

I am sure that React is only re-rendering when new data is available, the issue is that new data is available 100 times as per the 100 events which are emitted.

I am using redux-saga to manage the side effects in this app. Upon page load, i am dispatching the `FETCH_EVENT_DATA` action maybe 100 times for each event on the page (100). Its not possible to lazy load or paginate as they all need to be visible at once.

```
const fetchEventData = function* fetchEventData(params) {
  yield takeEvery("FETCH_EVENT_DATA", action => {
    params.socket.send(
      JSON.stringify({ type: "getEvent", id: parseInt(action.data) })
    );
  });
};
```

This results in `webSocketData(data)` being dispatched 100 times and as a result gradually 100 events pop in the page as each `webSocketData(data)` action is dispatched.

Ideally i would like to have a websocket event i can send called `getAllEvents` but that is not the case. Can anyone suggest a solution in order to wait for all the requests to come back before I dispatch an action or maybe even another solution I havent thought of?